# How to get dried paint out of washing machine?

Tags: painting

I'm trying to clean latex paint out of a front end loader washing machine. It was a towel that was soaked in paint. Chalk paint! It was thrown in my front end loader and I’ve been trying for 2 days to get it out. Still some sticky, and some very stuck. I’ve tried vinegar, baking soda, bleach etc.

Comment: Was it a can full from painting the drum or just some dried paint from cleaning clothes?

Comment: It’s was a towel that was soaked in paint. Chalk paint! It was thrown in my front end loader and I’ve been trying for 2 days to get it out. Still some and some sticky? Some very stuck

Comment: I’ve tried vinegar, baking soda, bleach ect

Comment: A serious washing machine cleaner may help, but you might be on a looser here. Any use of strong solvents may well get much of the paint off but could perish or destroy seals and pipes in the machine.

Comment: Besides the strong cleaner that could make it worse anything come to mind other than that? Washer is not old. It’s mostly speckled black spots like running your hand over sand but it’s stuck. And black

Comment: Is it affecting your washing? At this point you may risk damaging the washing machine if it doesn't affect the functionality. I know turpentine can remove latex paint, but it will destroy the seals. You may be able to spot dab it but you have to put effort to make sure you do not leak it into the drum.

Comment: Your best bet may be to just let it all dry and then get on with washing. Maybe wash and re-wash a load of low-value clothes to test. Hopefully the paint will (eventually/) stay put, looking bad but not affecting the results.

Comment: If it won't come off with cleaning, why not just leave it in place?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned

Answer (score 0):

I would try a latex paint remover if you don’t want to try that let it cure once it cures it may chip off a little at a time my wife sprays my paint clothes with a latex paint remover and washes them .